# Operator identity involving square root of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I would be most thankful if you could help me prove the following identity.
Let $A$ and $B$ be two completely continuous Hermitian operators on a Hilbert space $H$, such that $A$ and $B$ do not commute. If $A$ is a positive operator, then show that
$$\left\langle x, \left( \sqrt{A}B - B\sqrt{A}\right)x\right\rangle 
= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left\langle x, \left(B\frac{1}{A + \omega} - \frac{1}{A + \omega}B\right)x\right\rangle\sqrt{\omega}d\omega$$ for any $x\in H$.

It is known that for any $z$ and $z_0$ real and positive numbers one has
$$\sqrt{z} - \sqrt{z_0} = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{z_0 + \omega} - \frac{1}{z + \omega}\right)\sqrt{\omega}d\omega$$

Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't seem to be true for general Hilbert spaces. What is your $H$ exactly?

Comment: @Hui Yu $H$ is an arbitrary, possible separable, Hilbert space. Why do you say it's not true for a general Hilbert space? Do you have a counterexample?